# How to remove the hyperlink from all post dates where when you mouseover over the post date, a hyperlink displays like- “…com/2023/08/“

Tags: date-time

How can the “date” hyperlink be disabled? I want to keep the date text in posts (archive and single posts), without it linking anywhere.

Comment: Any link would be added by your theme. To remove it you would need to create a child theme and change the template in your child theme so that there's no link. The specific files etc. depends entirely on your theme, so I suggest speaking to its author.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Site Editor.

For the TwentyTwentyThree theme, you can find the option to disable the link with the steps below. A different template my require a different path through the template blocks or a child theme as suggested by Jacob Peattie in the Comments.

### Single posts

1. Navigate to the Site Editor page for the Single template
2. Select the List View
3. Navigate through these blocks: Group > Post Meta > Group > Columns > Column > Row > Post Date
4. Select **Post Date**
5. Using the Block Settings panel disable links using the option **Link to post**

### Archive posts

1. Navigate to the Site Editor page for the Archive template
2. Select the List View
3. Navigate through these blocks: Group > Query Loop > Post Template > Post Date
4. Select **Post Date**
5. Using the Block Settings panel disable links using the option **Link to post**